# Разъяснение по поводу авторизации. Как лучше организовать авторизацию PHP с COOKIE

Tags: php, mysql, cookie, auth

Хочу сделать систему авторизации но до конца не понимаю на сколько система с COOKIE безопасна. Я делаю так:

- пользователь регистрируется , вводит логин и пароль
- мы "солим" пароль логином и сохраняем хеш-функцию в базе данных
- когда пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль для входа мы опять получаем хеш-функцию с введенных только что логина и пароля и сравниваем значение с функцией которая у нас в базе данных
- если эти хеши совпадают то мы солим этот хеш на время или на ip и выдаем получившееся значение в качестве COOKIE пользователю. И это же значение записываем в базу данных в столбец cookie например
- и теперь когда пользователь заходит на наш сайт мы проверяем есть ли у него COOKIE и сравниваем их с тем значением, которое мы записали в столбец cookie в нашей базе данных.
- если эти куки совпадают, значит пользователь успешно авторизирован.

И получается ,что если эти куки взять из браузера и скопировать на другой компьютер и зайти на наш сайт с этого другого компьютера, то сервер проверит есть ли COOKIE с этим значение в нашей базе данных и если есть, то пропустит пользователя без проблем. И даже если мы укажем срок действия COOKIE один день например. Мы то в базу данных это значение куки записали навсегда. Оно из базы денных не удалится через день. И теоретически если злоумышленник один раз заполучил значение COOKIE то он постоянно сможет заходить на сайт и считаться авторизированым. Если кто-то может разъяснить ситуацию. Буду очень рад. Спасибо !

Comment: Хотел бы добавить еще одну важную штуку как csrf token. Рекомендую вам использовать во всех формах на сайте, где есть POST запросы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мы "солим" пароль логином и сохраняем хеш-функцию в базе данных

Не надо так делать. Уже даже в ядро [добавили функции](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) специально для обработки паролей.

И не надо больше ничего с этим хешом делать. Нужен какой-то токен для чего-то? Есть [random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.csprng.php) (и версия php не оправдание, в мануале есть ссылка на реализацию в пространстве пользователя).

> Мы то в базу данных это значение куки записали навсегда. Оно из базы денных не удалится через день.
>   Поскольку пользователю время жизни куки доверять нельзя - значит вам нужно рядом с токеном хранить и время его жизни.

Соответственно при авторизации генерируете токен. Поскольку штука важная для безопасности - то только через `CSPRNG`, криптостойким генератором. Никаких `rand`, `mt_rand` или `shuffle`. Полученный токен сохраняете в какой-то хранилище на сервере. Могу назвать два варианта:

- писать в табличку пользователя токен и дату выдачи токена. Затем сверять и токен и дату, не было ли это слишком давно
- писать отдельную табличку: `user_id`, `token`, `valid_until`. Можно ещё `ip`, `user agent` и ещё красиво показывать юзеру "недавно вы авторизовывались вот так и вот оттуда". Для каждой авторизации получили свой токен и своё время жизни, при необходимости можно отстреливать выборочно.

(табличка - понятие образное. Это можно хранить где угодно, а не только в РСУБД)

Не забудьте при смене пароля сбросить все токены. И не забудьте для кук выставить опциональные параметры, `httponly` точно, `secure` - если вы озадачились настройкой `https`.

Чисто для удобства можете ещё сохранить user_id в куку. Сама по себе публикация id опасности не представляет и зачастую id вообще публично-доступен, например, в url профиля на сайте, зато по нему искать проще.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то этот токен нужно передавать пользователю в куки. И для каждого токена у меня на сервере есть срок действия. И если этот срок действия меньше, чем время на сервере, то он является недействительным и пользователю нужно предложить авторизироваться снова.  И еще теоретически этот токен из куки можно скопировать на другой компьютер и оттуда зайти без проблем? И я никак не смогу это проверить и это самая основная уязвимость этих КУКИ как я понимаю да ?  и чтоб копирование куки не было уязвимостью нужно использовать сессии?

Comment: @dhNkolas, а вы разве не в курсе где сессии хранят свои идентификаторы? Да, да, в тех же самых куках, о которых вы так сильно волнуетесь. Куки же не просто так созданы, чтобы все кому не лень их воровали. Да, куки можно физически скопировать с одного компьютера на другой, но это уже не ваши проблемы, а проблемы пользователей, которые должны обеспокоится о безопасности своих компьютеров. Вы вот на куках упор делаете, а то что весь трафик и все данные по дороге между пользователем и сервером могут увести на сторону не думали? ;)

Comment: @Visman теперь более понятно. Спасибо )